# How to stop h2 database server and start h2 database Server Programming in java

Tags: database, spring, h2

I need to stop the server through server. and then start is again after 1 min .
This h2 database is configured inside our spring xml file configuration.

It would be really helpful if any one help me out.

After long struggle .. we cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a TCP server **inside** your application, use

```java
org.h2.tools.Server tcp = org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer("-tcpPort", "9999", …);
tcp.start();

.....

tcp.stop();
```

If you want to start it in a separate process, you can launch

```
java -cp h2-1.4.199.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 9999 -tcpPassword somePassword
```

to start the server and

```
java -cp h2-1.4.199.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcpShutdown tcp://localhost:9999 -tcpPassword somePassword
```

to stop it.

The default TCP port is 9092, it will be used if you don't specify another one.

Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(…)` or `ProcessBuilder` to execute these commands from your application.

Comment: Thanks Ryazanov. for answering my problem. Can we stop and start an existing h2 database server which was initialized through context file.

Comment: What do you mean by “context file”? You could try the same `-tcpShutdown` command without a password (or with password if it was configured somewhere), but it's not guaranteed to work if password wasn't set.

Comment: You cannot connect so some existing process and start the server in it unless you will include such feature in that process by yourself.